# Python code with google drive API doesn't give the access to send data

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

1. I am currently using MS SQL and Python for a basic level database system.
2. In this system i am going to save the data and when i need, than i need to send the datas to my customer's google drive.
3. I am using google drive cloud API and Google sheets API to manage this.
4. I am converting the sql tables to the excel sheets and i want to send this to my customer's google drive.

```
creds = None
client_secrets_file = r'C:\Users\Gürkan\Desktop\ana proje'  # Replace with the full path to your credentials.json file
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())


service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'sign_up',
    'parents': ['<folder-id>'],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
file_id = file.get('id')

# Upload CSV file to Google Sheets
file_metadata = {'name': 'sign_up', 'parents': [file_id]}
media = MediaFileUpload('sign_up.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
file = service.files().create(
    body=file_metadata,
    media_body=media,
    fields='id')
```

this is the code i used and i get Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Gürkan\Desktop\ana proje'

I don't know where the problem comes from. I checked my .json file and google API settings  seems work(both google drive and google sheets.)

Comment: are you sure the user your logging in with has permission to access that folder?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and it is working for me (I just made some modifications). Here is what I did:

1. I enable the Drive API and the Sheet API libraries for the project

   [image: libraries]
2. I created a `OAuth client ID` > `Desktop app`.

   [image: Google's OAuth]
3. I created a folder for the project, I stored the python code, a CSV file called `sign_up.csv` and the JSON file with the credentials (I named this file as credentials). Like this:

   [image: new folder]
4. I added these scopes:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

5. Since the `credentials.JSON` file is inside the same project as the python file project (`app.py`). I change the `client_secrets_file` variable to:

```
client_secrets_file = 'credentials.json'
```

6. I made a change in the `authorization flow` from:

```
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

to:

```
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                client_secrets_file, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

7. I made sure that I had `editor` permission over the `parents` folder in Google Drive.

---

The full code that I use was:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


def main():
    creds = None
    client_secrets_file = 'credentials.json' 

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                client_secrets_file, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())


    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'sign_up',
        'parents': ['<folder-id>'],
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
    }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    file_id = file.get('id')

    # Upload CSV file to Google Sheets
    file_metadata = {'name': 'sign_up', 'parents': [file_id]}
    media = MediaFileUpload('sign_up.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
    file = service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id')
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Reference:**

- [Drive Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Comment: Hello . Unfortunately, I was unable to respond to your reply because of  sickness a  family member. Thank you very much

Comment: @GurkanAli, not a problem. Did the answer help you solved the issue? Are you still getting error messages?